# Having errors with npm i google

Tags: node.js, npm

I try to add a search command for my bot, so I try to add the google extension with

`npm i google`

And I get :

```
npm WARN BAstLor@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN BAstLor@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN BAstLor@1.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ google@2.1.0
updated 1 package and audited 2557 packages in 8.968s

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 11 vulnerabilities (1 low, 7 moderate, 2 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

EDIT : I tried to continue my code, and tried to do other npm install, and I have the same errors with same vulnerabilities

EDIT2 : No more problem, thanks

Comment: What's the problem? Edit: these are warnings, not errors.

Comment: The problem is with vulnerabilities, I can't install other extension, like google, cron ....